# ANN and SVM classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, svm

Where is `ANN` classification (regression) better than `SVM`? Some real-world examples?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many applications where they're better, many applications where they're comparable, many applications where they are worse. It also depends on who you ask. It is hard to say this type of data or that type of data/application.

An example where ANN, in particular convolutional neural networks, work better than SVMs would be [digit classification on MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). Another such case is the work of [Geoff Hinton's group](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/) on speech recognition using Deep Belief Networks

Answer (score 4):

Recently I have read a paper of proving [the theoretical equivalence between ANN and SVM](https://web.archive.org/web/20070824050309/http://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/peter.andras/PAnpl2002.pdf). However, ANN is usually slower than SVM.

Comment: The link provided does not work.  Here is the actual reference: Andras, Peter. (2002). The Equivalence of Support Vector Machine and Regularization Neural Networks. Neural Processing Letters. 15. 97-104. 10.1023/A:1015292818897.

Answer (score 1):

I am just finishing some [out-of-the-box comparison between support vector machines and neural networks](https://web.archive.org/web/20120304030602/http://indiji.com/svm-vs-nn.html) on several popular regression- and classification datasets - first results in short: svms learn fast and predict slow - neural networks learn slow but predict fast and have very lightweight models. Concerning accuracy/loss, both methods seem to be on par.

Comment: after a year, I am unable to access the url. I can assume from title that I am missing a good text.

Answer (score 0):

It will largely depend as both have different tradeoffs and design criteria.  There has been some work to show the relationship and some say equivalence as seen in other answers to this question.  Below is another reference which draws links between these two techniques in machine learning:

> Ronan Collobert and Samy Bengio. 2004. Links between perceptrons, MLPs
>   and SVMs. In       Proceedings of the twenty-first international
>   conference on Machine learning (ICML  '04). ACM, New York, NY, USA,
>   23-. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1145/1015330.1015415